# Which model performance metric is used for SVR model by sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, loss-function, regularized

I noticed the math for SVR states that SVR uses L1 penalty or epsilon insensitive loss function. But sklearn SVR model documentation mentions L2 penalty. I don't have much experience with SVR thought the community who has experience could shed some light on this.

Here is the snippet from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html):

> C: float, default=1.0
>
> Regularization parameter. The strength of the
> regularization is inversely proportional to C. Must be strictly
> positive. The penalty is a squared **l2 penalty**.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-regression. quote -  *Here, we are penalizing samples whose prediction is at least  away from their true target*
[image]

Comment: So should I use MSE or MAE to check my SVR model's performance?